# Organization owner unable to login to Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, devops, owner

I am the owner of a Azure DevOps Organization. Since yesterday I am unable to login.

When I try to browse to my organization I can only "Request Access"

Tried to "Request Access", which I cannot grant because I cannot access the organization.

Comment: Are you certain it's the correct URL? i.e. `https://dev.azure.com/MyOrgName` I've found all cloud services can get very confused when you have multiple cloud logins. Have you also tried in incognito mode?

Comment: I always login via https://aex.dev.azure.com/me?mkt=en-US because I am a member of multiple organizations. The organization is displayed, behind the name it states (owner). The projects are not shown, it only shows a spinner. 

When I go to the https://dev.azure.com/MyOrgName I get '401 - Uh-oh, you do not have access.'

Comment: OK so definitely not a noob issue!

Answer (score 0):

Found the resolution myself.

1. Navigated to https://aex.dev.azure.com/me?mkt=en-US
2. Press F12 to go into developer tools
3. Clear local/session/shared storage and cookies
4. Closed the browser

After that I was able to login again.